# Migrating from APN to FCM

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, apn

We have this iOS application, we are sending push notifications to, using Apple Push Notification Service (APNs). We are now moving to Firebase Cloud Messenging (FCM) for sending notifications and we don't want to rebuild the app and release again. Is there a way to send notification through `FCM` to our users who have been registered through `APNs` using the (old) push notifications tokens.We have also tried the batchimport (change APN token to FCM token ).

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: key=SERVER API KEY" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
"application": "ApplciationID",
    "sandbox":false,
    "apns_tokens":[
    "BF939410B9F5D1A7411128A674951917A6CFCDFA0C1D304AEDCFFC2187FBB4Q1"
]}' "https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchImport"
```

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for that?

Comment: same question, was there any solution to this?